# Grouping days based on relative position

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

```
import datetime
dates_list = ['2015-03-28 10:15:36.560000', '2015-03-28 11:35:17.820000',
           '2015-03-29 13:34:54.380000', '2015-03-29 14:10:41.900000',
           '2015-03-31 16:55:43.680000', '2015-03-31 16:57:58.320000',
           '2015-04-02 18:54:31.480000', '2015-04-02 19:46:46.580000',
           '2015-04-03 20:58:27.940000', '2015-04-03 21:30:05.600000']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,np.nan,5,6,np.nan,np.nan,8,9],columns=['value'],index=[datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for date in dates_list])

df
Out[18]: 
                         value
2015-03-28 10:15:36.560    1.0
2015-03-28 11:35:17.820    2.0
2015-03-29 13:34:54.380    3.0
2015-03-29 14:10:41.900    NaN
2015-03-31 16:55:43.680    5.0
2015-03-31 16:57:58.320    6.0
2015-04-02 18:54:31.480    NaN
2015-04-02 19:46:46.580    NaN
2015-04-03 20:58:27.940    8.0
2015-04-03 21:30:05.600    9.0
```

I would like to compute 2 means: 1) groupin of the days in even positions **[2015-03-28, 2015-03-31, 2015-04-03]** and 2) grouping the days in even position [**2015-03-29 2015-04-02**].

In this case

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.index.day % 2).agg(np.mean)
```

won't work because the days are not consecutive and I am interested in the position of the days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create array by [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) and modulo `2` and use it for `groupby` with aggregating:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.factorize(df.index.date)[0] % 2).mean()
print (df)
      value
0  5.166667
1  3.000000
```

Detail:

```
print (pd.factorize(df.index.date)[0] % 2)
[0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
```